# two hdmi cables with different resolutions

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi

I'm using hdmi cable to connect my raspberry pi 4 to an ips display of 800X480. when I use one cable, it display one type of resolution, but when I use other cable, it display different type of resolution. how is this possible?

Comment: That should not happen. Maybe one of the cables may be faulty, have you checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For older HDMI versions, such as HDMI 1.4, there is no mechanism that makes it possible for the source (the Pi in your case) to get any feedback of the error rate of transmissions to the sink (your display).

The only information the source can gather is the the EDID information through the I2C/DDC link of the HDMI cable. This EDID information lists which resolutions, video timings, color formats etc are supported by the sink.

If you see different resolutions for different cables, the only thing I can think of is that somehow the communication over the EDID link broken. In that case, the source can select a video timing that all HDMI sinks must support (per HDMI specification.) One such resolution could be 640x480.